# How to add an UIView to a table cell in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have a `tableview` with 2 rows. In the first row I have an UIView and I'm gonna add a custom view on it. I made the custom view as a XIB and I'm adding it like following,

```
Layout6View *lookLayout6 = [[Layout6View alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,cell.mainView.frame.size.width, cell.mainView.frame.size.height)];
[cell.mainView addSubview:lookLayout6];
```

and my `Layout6View` looks like,

```
@implementation KCTLLookLayout6View

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Layout6"
                                          owner:self
                                        options:nil] lastObject];
        self.frame = frame;

    }

    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if (view == self.imageTopRightCorner) {
            view.frame = CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(0, 0, /*(self.frame.size.width/2)-20, (self.frame.size.height/3)*/30,30), 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
@end
```

When I'm running this, the custom view didn't resized. It's spread all over the table view(not only inside the cell).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Add subView on cell.contentView  or if you are design using storyboard directly add on it.

Comment: If possible prefer prototype cell on storyboard. As whenever you use "add subview" in cell then whenever cell reuses it will create again and overlap as many times cell reused. So you have to remove that view by iterating subviews and then do subview again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:lookLayout6];
```

Comment: You said you are defining `Layout6View ` in XIB file? But why are you not loading it from XIB? You must load it from XIB.

Comment: Try this `Layout6View *lookLayout6 = [[Layout6View alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNIB" bundle:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

Change the Size property of xib view. By default it is Inferred, make it Freeform and check.

[image]

Comment: I changed it. But facing the same problem.